# Problem about weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

I am reading a lecture note about Radon Riesz theorem, the resources is here: https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/notes/Radon-Riesz.pdf

At page 4, fourth line from the bottom, it says convergence in measure. But if this result is implied by weak convergence of $f_n$. I can’t proof it.

I have tried some methods, but this lead to a question about the definition of weak convergence. In the definition, which of the following one is exactly the real definition of weak convergence?

- for every $T\in X^*$, for all $\varepsilon>0$ May related to $T$, there is an $N$, such that for all $n>N$, $d(Tf_n, Tf)<\varepsilon$.
- for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $N$, such that for all $n>N$ and all $T$, $d(Tf_n, Tf)<\varepsilon$.

I checked some book but they generally says like
$$Tf_n\to Tf,\qquad \text{for all } T\in X^*$$

This makes curious for me.

Finally I almost forgot, if the definition is the second one I have proved: weak convergence implies convergence in measure, but if the definition is the first one, the prove failed, I also need a prove or a counterexample that weak convergence can’t imply convergence in measure, I also want to know how the lecture note get the result about convergence in measure if there is really an counterexample. THX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is false. To see this, if $T$ is a (fixed) continuous linear functional, then any constant multiplied by $T$ is also a continuous linear functional. Then the second statement is essentially asking for 
$$|cT(f_n) - cT(f)| = c|T(f_n) - T(f)| \leq \epsilon$$ 
for any constant $c$.

The first one is (almost) correct, the $\epsilon$ is still arbitrary, just now $N$ is allowed to depend on $T$.

In general, weak convergence does not imply convergence in measure, take $f_n(x) = \chi_{[n, n+1)}(x)$ which weakly converges to zero in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $1<p<\infty$, but fails to converge in measure .

Comment: I've got it, yes, for $X^*\cong L^q$, so for every $g\in L^q$, we can define $Tf:=\int fg$ which is finite linearity(linear is obvious, finite is ensured by Holder inequality), then by $\int_{[n,n+1)}g\to 0$ implies weakly converges to zero.

Comment: I re-checked the notes in the link, and retried to understand the document in the fourth page, so $\{f_n\}\to f$ in measure is false? although by $|f|^{p-2}f\in L^q$, so that $Tg:=\int |f|^{p-2}fg$, $\forall g\in L^p$ is a bounded linear functional, and weakly convergence imply $Tf_n\to Tf$ directly without converge in measure.